# Using a NodeJS Library from Java using Rhino and Rhinodo

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, rhino

I'm trying to use the Javascript library [multilang-extract-comments](https://github.com/nknapp/multilang-extract-comments) from within a Java application, so I decided to use Rhino as the Javascript engine and Rhinodo to interface between Rhino and NodeJS. However, I cannot figure out how to actually use Rhinodo. I've looked at the code for the projects that use Rhinodo (maven plugins for brunch, jshint, and recess), but I find the code to be pretty arcane. I've tried implementing code like the following (with some editing for my application):

```
rhinodoBuilder
            .destDir(rhinodoDestDir)
            .moduleFactory(nodeModuleProvider)
            .consoleFactory(wrappingConsoleFactory)
            .env(env)
            .build(new BaseFunction() {
                @Override
                public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args) {
                    Scriptable brunch = (Scriptable) ScriptableObject.callMethod(cx, scope, "require",
                            new Object[]{Context.javaToJS("brunch", scope)});

                    Scriptable options = cx.newObject(scope);
                    ScriptableObject.putProperty(options, "minify", minify);
                    System.setProperty("user.dir", userDir.getAbsolutePath());

                    ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptableObject.getTypedProperty(brunch, "build", Function.class),
                            cx, scope, thisObj, new Object[]{
                            options,
                            new BaseFunction() {
                                @Override
                                public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args) {
                                    return Undefined.instance;
                                }
                            }
                    });

                    return Undefined.instance;
                }
});
```

(from the brunch maven plugin)

However, this code doesn't work for me. I either get an error in trying to find my Javascript library or, when I use a library it should be able to find (I used fs as an example), I get a NullPointerException. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Note: both Rhinodo and the maven plugins that use it can be found in [MuleSoft's GitHub Repositories](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way for this to work out. However, if anyone else is determined to use Rhinodo in this way, part of the problem was that I wasn't actually using a NodeModuleProvider. In order to try and load my required Node modules, I used code similar to the following:

```
// create a module provider for all the node modules in META-INF
String prefix = "META-INF/node_modules/";
String[] moduleNames = {"amodule","anothermodule","modulethethird"};
ArrayList<NodeModuleImpl> moduleList = new ArrayList<NodeModuleImpl>();

for (String module: moduleNames) {
    moduleList.add(NodeModuleImplBuilder.fromFolder(prefix+module));
}
NodeModuleProviderImpl nmp = new NodeModuleProviderImpl(moduleList);
```

I then used the NodeModuleProvider in the RhinodoBuilder.moduleFactory() method (which you can see used in my code snippet in the question). However, be warned that you may have to solve the problem which I couldn't: using imported modules later from Rhino.

In the end I decided that it made much more sense to call my javascript as a command using exec, so I recommend that anyone else who undertakes something similar just use that solution.